# Meaning of "In"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, conjunctions

I have a question about the meaning of "*in*" in these two sentences :

> 1. The law ***in*** the way it applies to education does not affect this school.
> 2. He carried himself well ***in*** the way he handled the situation.

Is the "*in*" in the first sentence the same as the "*in*" in the second sentence?

Comment: @snailplane I wrote both sentences.

Comment: @J.R.  It is very different.

Comment: Of course it is. But you've [asked about this "in the way" question often enough](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6362+in+the+way).

Answer (score 1):

I see two different uses of in in these sentences, which I will paraphrase to show their meanings:

> The law, **inasmuch** as it applies to education...
>
> [I admire] **how he handled** the situation [with such poise,
>   professionally, bravery, etc.]

Note that sentenced (1) can be improved with commas:

> The law, in the way it applies to education, does not affect this
>   school.

Even so, I don't consider this sentence idiomatic. It would be improved with **inasmuch**.